# Find latest value earlier than specified date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have exchange rate table in which there are multiple date wise records with exchange rate.

```
Date           Rate
17/05/2012     5
23/05/2012     6
27/05/2012     7
```

Now I want rate while passing any date like if, I pass 20/05/2012 then rate 5 should return because 20/05/2012 elapse in date range 17 and 23 may 2012.

Comment: Please use unambiguous date formats. For SQL Server the safest is `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have correct datatypes (that is, not varchar to store date values...)

```
SELECT TOP 1
  Rate
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  DateColumn <= '20120520'
ORDER BY
  DateColumn DESC
```

Comment: If one more record existed in the sample data, like '16/5/2012', 4, wouldn't your query would return 4 instead of 5?

Comment: @ChrisGessler: I use "TOP 1" so we get the only the latest row before 20120520. "Latest" is defined by the descending sort of the DateColumn

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
select Rate from tablename where Date in (
  select max(Date) as Date
  from tablename
  where Date <= convert(datetime, '20/05/2012', 103)
  )
```

Comment: @Chris I disagree. Other users might come across this answer and think that d/m/y is ok. It's not. Please read : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @ChrisGessler: if you code defensively, or need to support different settings, you'd use yyyymdd. Example: you are a vendor and don't know what @@DATEFORMAT or language is used.

Comment: @Chris no, that is the point. People should use safe, unambiguous and language-neutral date formats. That way the reader doesn't have to care about the format or their regional settings or their language settings - and the same code will work for all readers. Please *read* the blog post I pointed you to...

Comment: @Chris `yyyy-mm-dd` is absolutely not correct. It can fail if the language is French, for example. I guess you didn't get too far into my blog post. You want to provide answers with literal strings like `d/m/y`, because that's what the OP has, be my guest. Just be aware that other readers might not have the same settings, so making those assumptions in an answer is not very helpful to anyone (except maybe the OP - whose system or session settings might also change after implementing the answer). I give up.

Comment: @Chris I don't have an answer, since gbn has a perfectly suitable answer. I'm commenting on someone else's answer (and the comments) just like you are. And I'm trying to help you better understand why "No need to format" is bad advice for an answer on a site like this - you were suggesting that it could just be `WHERE Date <= '20/05/2012'` and I'm sorry but that is just wrong.